# socket.io installation with npm

Tags: node.js, installation, socket.io, npm, node-gyp

I installed Python 2.7 (had 3.4) and solved one error. Then, I installed Windows 7 SDK, solved another error, but no luck... I read here that I don't have to install Visual Studio as well... Can someone enlighten me with a solution?

The screenshots:

[image: Screenshot part 1]

[image: Screenshot part 2]

Answer (score 1):

Assure this runs clean prior to your above install

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Do you have a c compiler installed ?

Are you creating a new nodejs app ?  If so then issue this which will prompt you for details then cut a fresh package.json file for you :

```
npm init
```

Comment: I installed node-gyp and created package.json. I am new, so I forgot about npm init... But it didn't solve it.

I thought that I get c compiler with SDK. Am I wrong?

Thank you for your help, by the way.

Comment: dunno ... I use linux so I have no Windows machine available ... please update your post with current error messages

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Windows is not the best for development , I have so much problems using Windows (and had the same problem), later I've switched to Ubuntu (just learn more Linux and C) - it has so much built-in programs so you don't have to install it by yourself (and you won't have any problems with that little problems and get even more knowledge).

Comment: I agree with you totally, but the tutorial I found to be the easiest and clearest to a beginner like me is on Windows. As I don't know what bumps along the way I can encounter by switching platforms, I was going to stick to it...

Comment: It's your choice, but still as you use `socket.io` this means you are web developer - which means you'll have to deal with servers, servers nowadays are powered by Linux (Ubuntu, OpenBSD, CoreOS), some knowledge about Linux will be worth it - security of your server, C knowledge (some libraries and other stuff), ShellScript knowledge which is much better than DOS. You know it's just my opinion. Don't stick with windows, I've used Windows for years and used Ubuntu for months, I'm really sad that I didn't use Ubuntu before - I would have so much more knowledge xD, but it's still you choice ;)

Comment: I am familiar with the terminal and used mint before, although not much. As I said, it's not about my opinion of Windows, I have many reasons to love it as a user and much more to hate it as a "developer". It's about the fact that I'm just getting started with node.js and don't know what to expect if I try to follow a Windows-based tutorial on Linux-based OS :P But thank you for your opinion and the much-justified advice :)

Comment: Oh, I love Node.js, I just don't get some people who hate it (and JavaScript) :( Yeah, I agree windows is very user friendly, if you still want to keep windows, you can just install Ubuntu on VirtualBox or dual boot it :3 so that you'll have two OS on your computer ;)

Comment: We don't seem to understand each other :D I do have mint on oracle's virtual box, but I don't switch to it because the tutorial which I can understand the most of is on Windows. And I don't know enough about node to be shure that I can watch the tutorial done on Windows, but follow it on Mint :)